# Override javascript property with getter/setter while still accessing underlying property

Tags: javascript

In service of building an API polyfill I'd like to override a property (in this case width and height) of an element with getters and setters to catch changes to the value and modify it before passing it on to the underlying element. Ideally this process would also be reversible. Something along the lines of this code snippet:

```
var realWidth = null;

function patch(targetObject) {
 realWidth = targetObject.magicalPropertyAccessor("width");
 Object.defineProperty(targetObject, 'width', {
    get: function() {
      return realWidth / 2;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      realWidth = value * 2;
    }
  });
}

function unpatch(targetObject) {
  if (realWidth)
    targetObject.magicalPropertySetter('width', realWidth);
}
```

The intention of the example being that while the element is patched it will silently double changes to it's dimensions while reporting back the original, unaltered value. If this was a function it would be pretty straightforward, but as a property it's unclear how to cache a reference to the original accessor.

Comment: You mean that the overwritten property was a getter/setter as well?

Comment: I guess the ideal solution would be one that handles either, but in my case no, just a property. (I'm thinking specifically of the width and height of a canvas element)

Comment: I believe you're looking for [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor), but I'm not sure it'll work on host objects like a canvas.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Bergi I figured out that `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` is exactly what I want. I had tried it previously but missed that the property that I had to go to the object's `__proto__` to find the property I was looking for. (Your milage may vary depending on the property you're replacing.) This is the code that worked for me:

```
function WidthPatch(canvas) {
  var self = this;
  var fakeWidth = canvas.width;
  this.canvas = canvas;

  // Cache the real property
  this.realWidthProp = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(canvas.__proto__, 'width');

  // Replace the property with a custom one
  Object.defineProperty(canvas, 'width', {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    get: function() {
      return fakeWidth;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      fakeWidth = value;
      // This updates the real canvas property, silently doubling it.
      self.realWidthProp.set.call(canvas, fakeWidth * 2);
    }
  });
}

WidthPatch.prototype.unpatch = function() {
  // Replace the custom property with the original one.
  Object.defineProperty(this.canvas, 'width', this.realWidthProp);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work on iOS. `this.realWidthProp` ends up having undefined `get` and `set` fields, so when you restore it, width is no longer modifiable. Also, `this.realWidthProp.configurable` is false by default, and needs to be flipped to true manually (with `this.realWidthProp.configurable = true`). Is there a way to get at the setters and getters manually?

Answer (score 0):

[Reflect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) offers some nice(r) syntax for this particular use-case.

The demo below implements a "WidthPatch" class that overrides a "width" property, returning a value that is 2x the actual value, while simultaneously providing access to the actual value via a new "actualWidth" property.  The "UnPatch" method deletes the modified property, reverting to the original behavior.

```js
class WidthPatch {

    static #propertyName = 'width';
    static #shadowPropertyName = 'actualWidth';
    
    static Patch(instance) {
        Reflect.defineProperty(instance, WidthPatch.#shadowPropertyName, {
            get: _ => WidthPatch.#get(instance)
        });
        Reflect.defineProperty(instance, WidthPatch.#propertyName, {
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            get: _ => 2 * WidthPatch.#get(instance),
            set: value => Reflect.set(Reflect.getPrototypeOf(instance), WidthPatch.#propertyName, value, instance)
        }); 
    }
    
    static UnPatch(instance) {
        Reflect.deleteProperty(instance, WidthPatch.#propertyName);
    }
    
    static #get(instance) {
        return Reflect.get(Reflect.getPrototypeOf(instance), WidthPatch.#propertyName, instance);
    }
}


class Demo {
    static {
    
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        
        console.log(`width (initial): ${canvas.width}`);
        
        WidthPatch.Patch(canvas);        
        console.log(`width (after patching): ${canvas.width}, actualWidth: ${canvas.actualWidth}`);
        
        canvas.width = 200;
        console.log(`width (after setting to 200): ${canvas.width}, actualWidth: ${canvas.actualWidth}`);
        
        WidthPatch.UnPatch(canvas);
        console.log(`width (after unpatching): ${canvas.width}, actualWidth: ${canvas.actualWidth}`);
        
    }
}
```